# Instantiate self-bounded generic in java

Tags: java, generics

Possibly a simple question, but I can't seem to do this for some reason. How do I instantiate an object of type BinaryTree from the class below:

```
public class BinaryTree<N extends BinaryTree.BTNode<N>> {

public static class BTNode<N extends BTNode<N>> {
    public N left;
    public N right;
    public N parent;    
}
//some methods which return variables of type N
//or take variables of type N as arguments
}
```

Both:

```
BinaryTree<BTNode> tree = new BinaryTree<BTNode>();
```

and:

```
BinaryTree<BTNode<BTNode>> tree = new BinaryTree<BTNode<BTNode>>();
```

generate a compiler error in Eclipse saying the type BTNode is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter N extends BTNode.

The reason for this structure is that I want to be able to extend BinaryTree and BTNode and have the subclass call superclass functions which return variables of type N, and have N be of the type of the subclass of BTNode, not of type BTNode.

I feel like I may be missing something obvious here, but I've searched extensively and spent a decent amount of time trying different things and I remain unable to do this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think for this intermediate class, you cannot give a better generic parameter than the following: `BinaryTree<? extends BTNode<?>> tree = new BinaryTree<>();` For more concrete implementations this will work as you expected.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly an answer to your problem, but I think your problem is caused by a suboptimal design. Keep your types simple! For a binary tree, I would expect the type parameter to be the type of the *data* in the tree, i.e. the type of the labels of the nodes. Since you can use type variables as type parameters also, this should be exactly what you want.

```
public class BinaryTree<E> {

    public static class BTNode<T> {
        public T label;
        public BTNode<T> left;
        public BTNode<T> right;
        public BTNode<T> parent; 
    }
    //some methods which return variables of type BTNode<E>. 
    //or take variables of type BTNode<E> as arguments
}
```

Comment: My first implementation looked like this. But then I tried to extend BTNode to have additional fields, and to extend BinaryTree to use the extended node type. For example I have XBinaryTree extends BinaryTree and XBTNode extends BTNode. And when calling inherited functions from XBinaryTree I get return types of BTNode, when I need return types of XBTNode.

Comment: Return type of the methods in the subclass can be subtypes of the return types of the overridden methods in the superclass. But this is only the case for returns types, not arguments. And what kind of extra fields do you want to add? If they are additional data, I would extends the data class and then use a `BinaryTree<ExtendedData>`, rather than modify the `BinaryTree` class.

Comment: So with all the classes structured as in my original question, everything compiles correctly and the return types are all correct (at least the compiler thinks they will be), but I can't test it out, since I can't actually instantiate an object of type 'BinaryTree<N extends BinaryTree.BTNode<N>>' or  'XBinaryTree<N extends XBinaryTree.XBTNode<N, E>, E>', which is the extended class where the nodes have elements attached to them

Comment: Typed my comment at the same time you were typing yours it appears. Anyway, thanks for your continued help. I will re-write for a bit and see what works.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured out how to do exactly what I was trying to do, which I thought I would post for posterity's sake.

Basically, I had

```
Class Node<N extends Node<N, E>, E> {
    N left, right, parent;
    E element;
```

and

```
Class Tree<N extends Node<N, E>, E> {
    N rootNode;
    N externalNode;
    public N findNode(E e)   //returns the node with element e
    public boolean add(E e)  //adds a new node of type N with 
                             //  element e to the tree
    //etc
```

The purpose of structuring it like this is so that if it's extended later the subclasses can call superclass methods, including the constructors, and have the right type of N be created or returned.  I have a generic node that can be extended, and a generic tree that can be extended, and when using descendants of either I can call the superclasses add(E e) method and be sure the right type of N containing e is created and added, etc...

For example:

```
Class XNode<N extends XNode<N, E>, E> extends Node<N, E> {
```

and

```
Class XTree<N extends XNode<N, E>, E> extends Tree<N, E> {
```

Anyway, the problem I had is that I couldn't instantiate an object of type `Node<N extends Node<N, E> E>` because no matter what I passed as a parameter I was getting the error `<parameter> is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter N extends Node<N, E>, E`.

The solution was to create a class:

```
Class SampleNode<E> extends Node<SampleNode<E>, E>
```

I added a field N sample; to the Tree class, and changed the constructor of Tree so that an instance of the sample node type can be passed. Now I can instantiate with:

```
SampleNode<ElementType> sample = new SampleNode<ElementType>();
Tree<SampleNode<ElementType>, ElementType> tree 
    = new Tree<SampleNode<ElementType>, ElementType>(sample);
```

and create new nodes in the tree with:

```
public N newNode() {
   return (N)(sample.getClass().newInstance())  //needs try-catch and
                                                //  suppress unchecked
```

Anyway, I'm not sure if anyone cares, but I thought I'd post the solution anyway.